# Can you pass a short into a method call when an int is expected?

Tags: java

Can you pass a short into a method call when an int is expected?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, a short will be automatically promoted to an int.

Comment: Yes, the data types will be converted. See [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible. As the comments pointed out, the value can easily be widened.

```java
void someMethod(int number) {} // some method
// ...
short n = 10;
someMethod(n); // easy peasy
```

However, while casting from an int to a short is possible, you must be careful because a short is, well, shorter. It can't hold as many values as an int, possibly truncating the value.

Comment: This unfortunately isn't correct. There is no need to cast a short to an int as the conversation (known as "widening") will happen automatically. You can remove the cast in your code and it will make no difference. Its possible that the compiler will even realize the unnecessary cast and remove it automatically.

Comment: **DONT** remember the cast.